# Refactor LINQ-to-SQL class in new namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a LINQ-to-SQL Generator class in a project I'm working on, and to conform to naming conventions, the default namespace has to be a little different than the name of the project itself.

Essentially, it has to be GroupName.ProjectName, instead of just ProjectName.

I can manually rename stuff and that's fine, except for the LINQ-to-SQL class we have in the project.

Renaming the namespace manually just causes the change to be wiped out next time the tool is regenerated.  Any help on getting this refactored properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind.  I am an idiot and thought this would be handled at the solution level and not the project level.  For what it's worth, right click on your project file, click properties, and edit the "default namespace" field.

Comment: +1 I was assuming there had to be some kind of a config setting for this.... :-) Manually modifying generated classes is never a very good idea, in the long run...

Comment: To clarify, I meant manually renaming the other classes I've coded, which don't rewrite themselves.  The Linq-to-sql class was unique in that it did that.